# Edit table in pyqt using QAbstractTableModel

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt4, pyside, qabstracttablemodel

I'm trying to create an editable table in PyQt. Here's the code for just displaying the table:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

# données à représenter
my_array = [['00','01','02'],
            ['10','11','12'],
            ['20','21','22']]

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

# création de la vue et du conteneur
class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args)

        tablemodel = MyTableModel(my_array, self)
        tableview = QTableView()
        tableview.setModel(tablemodel)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(tableview)
        self.setLayout(layout)

# création du modèle
class MyTableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, datain, parent = None, *args):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent, *args)
        self.arraydata = datain

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.arraydata)

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.arraydata[0])

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None
        elif role != Qt.DisplayRole:
            return None
        return (self.arraydata[index.row()][index.column()])

    """
    def setData(self, index, value):
        self.arraydata[index.row()][index.column()] = value
        return True
    def flags(self, index):
        return Qt.ItemIsEditable
    """    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If I implement the method `setData` and `flags`, all the items are not even selectable...
What is the solution to make tha table editable?
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've just found the solution, in the flags methods need to return the value `QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable`

Comment: This works. You can also OR the already existing flags with the `ItemIsEditable` flag: `QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.flags(self, index) |
                QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable`

Comment: I tried your code. To work, I needed to change **def setData(self, index, value)** to **def setData(self, index, value, role)**

Answer (score -2):

```
OR Override
Qt::ItemFlags MyTableView::flags(const QModelIndex& index) const
{
    Qt::ItemFlags flags = QAbstractTableModel::flags(index);
    flags |= Qt::ItemIsEditable;
    return flags;
}
```

Comment: @bigOTHER Not to mention, this code is in C++ while the question is regarding Python.