# PyQt custom widget not showing

Tags: python, qt, widget, pyqt5

I'm new to PyQt.

I'm trying to put a QTableView in a class, so I can define it's behaviour in the class without mixing it with all the other code, but when I do so it just won't show.

Here's the code i'm learning from. It was borrowed from [ [Edit table in pyqt using QAbstractTableModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736560/edit-table-in-pyqt-using-qabstracttablemodel) ]. Readapted it slightly to use with Qt5 and moved the QTableView in a class

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QPushButton, QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QTableView, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

# données à représenter
my_array = [['00','01','02'],
            ['10','11','12'],
            ['20','21','22']]

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

# création de la vue et du conteneur
class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args)

        tablemodel = MyTableModel(my_array, self)
        table = Table(tablemodel)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(table)
        self.setLayout(layout)

# création du modèle

class Table(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, model):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = model
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setMinimumSize(300,300)
        self.view = QTableView()
        self.view.setModel(self.model)


class MyTableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, datain, parent = None, *args):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent, *args)
        self.arraydata = datain

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.arraydata)

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.arraydata[0])

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            return None
        elif role != Qt.DisplayRole:
            return None
        return (self.arraydata[index.row()][index.column()])

    """
    def setData(self, index, value):
        self.arraydata[index.row()][index.column()] = value
        return True
    def flags(self, index):
        return Qt.ItemIsEditable
    """    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If I remove the class and use

```
table = QTableView()
table.setModel(tablemodel)
```

the table shows no problem.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you tried returning the data without the ``tuple`` (directly returning ``self.arraydata[row][column]``)?

Comment: Same result. There's no widget showing. I just see a blank window. No grid, no header.

It is 300x300 as defined by
        setMinimumSize(300,300)

Answer (score 2):

You defined `Table`as a `QWidget` with an attribute `self.view=QTableView`. 
But you didn't define a layout on `Table`, so it will be displayed as an empty widget.

You either have to define a layout for `Table`, and add the view to it, or directly add the view to the main window's layout:

```
class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args)

        tablemodel = MyTableModel(my_array, self)
        table = Table(tablemodel)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(table.view)  #add view instead of table
        self.setLayout(layout)
```

A third way is to change the definition of `Table`: you could subclass `QTableView` instead of `QWidget` (code not tested):

```
class Table(QTableView):
    def __init__(self, model, parent):
        super(Table,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setMinimumSize(300,300)
        self.setModel(model)
```

Comment: Thanks. I see the mistake now and it's really stupid. Shame on me! haha

Answer (score 2):

the problem: table.view has no parent. If you add `self.view.show()` to test to `Table.initUi()`, you get two widgets, `MyWindow` with empty table as tmoreau wrote and `table.view` as isolated widget.

You can either pass a parent when constructing `table.view` in `Table.initUi()`

```
self.view = QTableView(self)
```

(then you don't need a layout) or add table.view to a layout as written by tmoreau, [Then the tableview is reparented.](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html)

Removing the class has the same effect, then the tableview is added to layout.